# Powershell Change path in variable

Tags: powershell

i need you help again :D

I have created a function to put the error logs in a file who take the name of my script (i call multiples scripts so it's very helpful), here is my function :

```
function ExportLog{
$path = Get-Location

$LogFile = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($MyInvocation.ScriptName,"log")
Write-Host $LogFile
$timestamps = Get-Date
$string_err = $_ | Out-String
$ExportError = "[" + $timestamps.DateTime + "]`n" + $string_err + "`n"| Out-File -FilePath $LogFile -Append

Read-Host “Appuyez sur ENTRER pour quitter...”}
```

This works fine but the log file created or edited is in the path of my script.

My question is how can i add \log\ in the path who is in my variable $LogFile ?

I tried to use Join-Path, but it just add path like this : C:\import\Modif_CSV.log\Logs ... I wan't to add the Logs folder before the name of the file ^^

Ty for help :)

Comment: `(Join-Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'log') $LogFile)`

Comment: This don't work, this give me : c:\import\logs\modif_csv.log\ , the name of the file is a folder name ... I found the solution, ty for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the current script filename from the full path and change the extension with:

```
$LogFileName = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension((Split-Path $PSCommandPath -Leaf), 'log')
```

Next combine the current script path with the subfolder 'log' and with the new filename

```
$LogFullName = [IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, 'log', $LogFileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68863871/45375) shows a .NET API-based solution that works in both *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.

Here's **a *PowerShell (Core) 7+* solution** that showcases **new features** (relative to Windows PowerShell):

```bash
$dir, $name = $PSCommandPath -split '\\', -2
Join-Path $dir log ((Split-Path -LeafBase $name) + '.log')
```

- `-split '\\', -2` splits the path into two strings by `\`: the *last* `\`-separated token, preceded by *everything before the last* `\`, thereby effectively splitting a file path into its directory path and file name. That is, **`-split` now accepts a *negative* number as the count of tokens to return**, with `-$n` meaning: return `$n-1` tokens  from the *right* of the input string (albeit in left-to-right order), and save any remaining part of the string in the return array's *first* element; e.g., `'a/b/c/d' -split '/', -3` yields `'a/b', 'c', 'd'`
- [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path) **`-LeafBase` returns a file path's file-name *base*, i.e. the file name *without its extension***.
- **[`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) now accepts an *open*-ended number of child paths to join to the parent path**; e.g., `Join C:\ dir subdir` now works to create `C:\dir\subdir`, whereas in Windows PowerShell you had to *nest* calls: `Join-Path (Join-Path C:\ dir) subdir`

Note: It would be handy if `Split-Path` supported returning *all* components of a given path in a *single* operation; [GitHub issue #6606](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6606) proposes an `-All` switch that returns an *object* whose properties reflect all the constituent parts of the path, which would enable the following simplified solution:

```bash
# WISHFUL THINKING, as of PowerShell 7.2
$pathInfo = Split-Path -All $PSCommandPath
Join-Path $pathInfo.Parent log ($pathInfo.LeafBase + '.log')
```